# Стоит ли изучать "OpenGL. Профессиональное программирование трехмерной графики на C++" сегодня

Tags: c++, opengl

Подойдёт ли данная книга новичку и насколько она будет актуальна сегодня?

Comment: Очень уж она старая, 2004 год. В том же году вышел OpenGL 2.0, но в описании книги упоминается "OpenGL версии 1.2 и выше", и мне почему-то кажется, что речь только про 1.x.

Comment: Тогда что можно взять свежее и на русском?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал подучить английский и почитать гайды [отсюда](https://learnopengl.com) (без прокси может не открыться, видимо РКН шалит).

Comment: Новичку в первую очередь следует изучать английский язык. К сожалению, разница в количестве книг/статей/документации на русском и английском драматическая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую почитать вот эту книгу [link](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/catalog/book/839281/).  В ней описано какие есть функции на момент 3.0 версии opengl. Также затрагиваются шейдеры, без которых никак.

Comment: Это будет глупым вопросом но чем отличается opengl от opengl es?

Comment: @alexseybobrovitch OpenGL ES - урезанная версия OpenGL для мобилок.

Comment: @Suvitruf Причем сначала урезанная, а потом расширенная.

Comment: @xverizex А для ПК он подойдёт?

Comment: Да, пойдет, там нужные функции для отрисовки показываются. Я вот например пишу игру, используя opengl es. Пиши на пк, тестирую а потом на мобилку можно закинуть и она там работать будет.

Comment: Можно без шейдеров выводить так ещё, вершинные координаты с помощью glVertexPointer, цвета glColorPointer, и текстурные координаты вроде glTexCoordPointer. Но это уже не доступно в opengl > какой то версии. Я незнаю если честно, потому что в документации об этим функциях не написано. Но я знаю о них, да и в книгах о них не написано. Плохо что в книгах совсем уже древный способ написан вывода пикселей.

Comment: Хотя бы название книги напишите, а то такие ссылки протухают за 2-3мес.